# How to modify librtmp Makefile to remove version suffix?

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries

By default librtmp compile produces `librtmp.so.1` file and symlink `librtmp.so`. I need to have librtmp.so without number suffix as andorid does not support it.

I was able to modify Makefile to get librtmp.so file:

```
#SO_VERSION=1
#SO_posix=.${SOX}.${SO_VERSION}
SO_posix=${SOX}
```

so the file produced file is now `librtmp.so`

But android can't load it as it still tries to load `librtmp.so.` (with dot):

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1891]:   170 could not load needed library 'librtmp.so.' for 'libffmpeg.so' (load_library[1093]: Library 'librtmp.so.' not found)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a shared library has `DT_SONAME` dynamic tag of `foobar.so.56`, then no matter what you call the actual file (e.g. `foo.so`, or `libbar.so`), when you use that library to link an executable, the `SONAME` is recorded in the executable (as `DT_NEEDED` dynamic tag), and not the actual file name.

It follows that your `librtmp.so` has a `DT_SONAME` of `librtmp.so.`. You can confirm that with:

```
readelf -d librtmp.so | grep SONAME
```

So what do you need to do to get rid of `SONAME`? Get rid of `-Wl,--soname=...` somewhere in your `Makefile`.

> how can i check executable if it uses `SONAME` or filename

The executable will *always* use `SONAME` (if present). You can check the libraries that executable needs by looking for `DT_NEEDED` tags in the executable's dynamic section:

```
readelf -d a.out | grep NEEDED
```

Comment: how can i check executable if it uses SONAME or filename?

Comment: In Android NDK r9d, this simple trick does not work, unfortunately. NDK adds DT_SONAME to your shared libs automatically. Worse, if you really try hard and remove this field, then the file name is still **NEEDED** by the dependent shared library.