# Unsatisfied link for .so.12 file in android shared library

Tags: android-ndk, linker, static-libraries

I am building libexif for Android. I am using the following cross compile script:

```
PLATFORM_PREFIX=/home/tishu/Documents/osx-wks/GC/Thdl/jni/libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/
NDK_PATH=/home/tishu/Documents/android-ndk-r8e/
NDK_PLATFORM=android-14

rmdir $PLATFORM_PREFIX
mkdir $PLATFORM_PREFIX

$NDK_PATH/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh  --system=linux-x86_64 --platform=$NDK_PLATFORM --install-dir=$PLATFORM_PREFIX

PATH=$PLATFORM_PREFIX/bin:$PATH

./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=$PLATFORM_PREFIX --enable-static
make clean
make install
```

The output gives 3 .so files in the lib folder

- libexif.so (symlink)
- libexif.so.12 (looks like a symlink but content is big binary)
- libexif.so.12.3.3 (actual binary)

I have renamed the last file to libexif.so and deleted the two symlinks as per some advice found on this website. I then wanted to build this with my app and use the following Android.mk, where libexif_native is my c file that uses the libexif library

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libexif
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/lib/libexif.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/lib/libexif.so
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := true
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=false
LOCAL_MODULE := libexif_native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libexif_native1.1.4.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := libexif
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -lm $(LOCAL_PATH)/libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/lib/libexif.so
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This compiles correctly, but when I run it on my phone in debug mode I get this error:

```
11-01 15:05:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(5638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-01 15:05:06.919: E/AndroidRuntime(5638): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: could not load library "libexif.so.12" needed by "libexif_native.so"; caused by library "libexif.so.12" not found
```

I then tried this modified Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libexif
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/lib/libexif.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/include
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/lib/libexif.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/lib/libexif.so.12
LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := true
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=false
LOCAL_MODULE := libexif_native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libexif_native1.1.4.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/include
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARY := libexif
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -lm $(LOCAL_PATH)/libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/lib/libexif.so.12 -lm $(LOCAL_PATH)/libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/lib/libexif.so.12
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

With no more luck.

Anyone knows why it is looking for the .12 file and how to pass it on? I have tried a few naive tweaks but can't find out how to make this work.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The library **`libexif.so`** is part of the standard Android distribution. If you don't rely on some special feature of the latest version, you may find that `/system/lib/libexif.so` will just be OK for you. Instead of building the library and working around all the troubles (see below), you can link your `libexif-native.so` with the system lib: simply pull the library from your device:

```
> adb pull /system/lib/libexif.so /somepath
```

and then insert

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += /somepath/libexif.so
```

into your **Android.mk**. Note that you will see

> Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:...: non-system libraries in linker flags: /somepath/libexif.so

In this speific case, you can safely ignore this warning.

### The troubles you avoid this way

It is a typical problem with Android port of Linux libraries, that the latter use version suffix for SONAME, while Android NDK does not support such suffix. There is a good reason for that: on Android, libraries are not installed system-wide, they are always part of the application package, and so version tagging is unnecessary. But this inconsistency does not make Android developers' lives easier.

The straightforward resolution was suggested in *[How to modify librtmp Makefile to remove version suffix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23155401/how-to-modify-librtmp-makefile-to-remove-version-suffix)*: Get rid of `-Wl,--soname=...` somewhere in your Makefile. Unfortunately, this trick does not work with NDK r9d, or r10c.

But you can specify extra `LDFLAGS` for `./configure`. Here is the command:

```
./configure LDFLAGS=-Wl,soname=libexif.so <other parameters>
make
mv /arch-arm/lib/libexif.so.12.3.3 /arch-arm/lib/libexif.so
```

Note that you also need to explicitly load the dependency libraries from Java, in the correct order. I.e. a static constructor will look like:

```
static {
    System.load("/data/data/your.package.name/lib/libexif.so");
    System.loadLibrary("exif-native");
}
```

You *must* specify the full path to `libexif.so` because otherwise the library from `/system/lib` will be loaded.

***Alternatively***, you should rename the library

```
./configure LDFLAGS=-Wl,soname=libexif.12.3.3.so <other parameters>
make
mv /arch-arm/lib/libexif.so.12.3.3 /arch-arm/lib/libexif.12.3.3.so
```

Now your Java code may be cleaner:

```
    System.loadLibrary("exif.12.3.3");
    System.loadLibrary("exif-native");
```

And here is the relevant fragment of **Android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_MODULE := libexif
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/lib/libexif.12.3.3.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/include
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

***Actually***, one trick that I never dared to try could be to manually pack the file `libexif.so.12` into the `assets` folder, unpack it to some known path after APK installs, and use

```
    System.load("/known/path/libexif.so.12");
    System.loadLibrary("exif-native");
```

It is a pity that the Android pack/install framework performs filtering of the files in `libs/armeabi` folder to only allow pattern `lib<whatever>.so`.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, I have a couple more questions on this:
- If I use the first quick method, which include folder should I use? I need it to code my own c file using the library
- I could not get the second one to work
    ./configure LDFLAGS=-Wl,-soname=libexif.12.3.3.so --host=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=$PLATFORM_PREFIX  --disable-static --enable-shared
    make clean
    make install

    mv arch-arm/lib/libexif.so.12.3.3 arch-arm/lib/libexif.12.3.3.so

then
     
    System.loadLibrary("exif.12.3.3");
    System.loadLibrary("exif_native");

I still get the error about so.12

Comment: Issue on point 2 is very likely incorrect configure parameters as i get the following readelf -d libexif.12.3.3.so | grep SONAME
 0x0000000e (SONAME)                     Library soname: [libexif.so.12]

Comment: Presumably, you can use the headers you downloaded with libexif from SourceForge. To be on the safe side, you can get the same [from `android.googlesource.com`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libexif/)

Comment: instead of `LDFLAGS`, it may be worth while to use **`LDLIBS`**.

Comment: For the first method, code does not compile when using the built in .so file. There are a lot of undefined symbol errors that break the build when switching to that system .so file in LOCAL_LDLIBS.
 LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -lm $(LOCAL_PATH)/libexif.so

Comment: Really? Can you post the build log on pastebin or something? The better format would be `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -lm -L$(LOCAL_PATH) -lexif`

Comment: On the second thought, you can simply download the source from [googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/libexif/+/master) to build the 6.21 version for Android on your PC. Here is the command: `ndk-build APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=libexif/Android.mk NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. LOCAL_C_INCLUDES=.`

Comment: Thanks for all the help, in the end I got it working by referencing the .a file: LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -lm $(LOCAL_PATH)/libexif-0.6.21/arch-arm/lib/libexif.a

Comment: This way, you use static linking to `libexif`. Please note that the library is available under LGPL, thus static linking may impose undesirable consequences.